# Create Rule from Message: Win 7? Where is it?

Tags: windows-live-mail, mail-rule, automated-builds

There are things I much prefer in Outlook Express to Windows Live Mail: one of those things is the ability to create a Mail Rule whilst viewing a message. You would simply do so andthe new rule would be created with the dialog box and all of its options/values filled in appropriately. Am I simply missing this or did this ability simply not make the cut?

Ross

Answer (score 0):

I found a way!

1. Right click on the message heading and select **Properties**, This will give you the incoming address/name.
2. Copy the name into the clipboard.
3. Open message rules and paste into the **where the subject line contains** people box.
4. Choose the destination folder and press OK.

Comment: I think s/he wants to create the message a little more directly then that...